# Instance Variables and Adding elements to end of array

Tags: c++

I am trying to see if I have initialized the instance variables correctly, and in the bool add(int element) method, that I would have to create a if statement to check if there's room, then how would I add an element to the end of an array?

```
#define DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE 1024

class SortableArray {

// Instance variable to store array in
int *arr;

// Instance variable to store the current count of the array
int count;

// Instance variable to store the size of the array
int max_size;

public:

// Default constructor
SortableArray()
//initialize the variables through constructors 10/6
{
    int *arr;
    int count = 0;
    int max_size = DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE;
}
// Constructor that takes int size as input
explicit SortableArray(int size)
{
    arr = new int[max_size];
    int count = 0;
    int max_size = size; 
}

// Adds element to end of array if there is room
// Returns true if successful
bool add(int element)
{
    if(count <= max_size) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: This needs a destructor if you're calling `new[]`.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Hint: Allocate, copy, switch pointers.